# Is possible classify audio file using naive bayes?

Tags: naive-bayes

I like use naive bayes classifier to classify audio file (.mp3).
I use Key,  Mode,  Loudness, Energy and Tempo as feature. So, the classifier will classify new file to 2 class, they are POP and ROCK. My question, is possible to use several (5) features to classify audio file?
Thanks!

Comment: In theory yes, but what percentage accuracy you achieve will depend on the training set and the discriminative ability of the 5 features you've chosen.  Other algorithms may perform better, but you would have to empirically test them. Do you know what accuracy level you are trying to achieve ?

Comment: Do you have labelled training examples  ?

Comment: Hi @image_doctor,
The fact is feature that i'll use are like this => 8, 1, -16.583, 0.361776, 156.105, that all Key, Mode, Loudness, Energy and Tempo. You see? they are continue value.

I just think, may be I'll only use one of them, but until now, I dont know which one of them is reliable value to use as feature.
Do you have suggestion for me about this thing?
About the accuracy, of course I will use confusion matrix method.
Sir, In fact Im not too sure what i talking about right now, I still confuse.
At pass, I successfully working with KNN to classify text. that's all my experiences.

Comment: Yes I have, I got it from echonest.com

Comment: If you have 5 pieces of information to help you select a Pop or Rock, why would you choose to throw away information and use only one? Do you have some other constraint that you must use only one feature ? If you want to know the relative power of the different features you have, look at a group of techniques known as 'Feature Selection'.  5 is not a lot of features, so you should probably use all of them. You might want to consider other methods apart from Naive Bayes such as Random Forests or SVMs or even KNN which you are familiar with.

Comment: For sure,
Tell me lazy man.
I just think that if I use naive bayes to proceed that feature whitout anything else special step, its imposible to do.
But about using KNN, I still thinking about it.
For sure, I dont know how to do with this thing, So I can perform classification step in algorithm (probability formulas).
This is my data example: 
http://i61.tinypic.com/6zn480.jpg

Comment: If you have enough training data and that data is sufficiently discriminative, then Naive Bayes can work. But without trying the algorithms on the data you have and seeing their results, it is very hard to say what error rate you will achieve, or if an alternate algorithm will perform better. have you tried using say, WEKA or R, to see how the data you have performs?

Comment: How large is your data set ? The data example you give is too small to build a meaningful classifier, I presume you have more data to use ? I'd point out that the features "Key" and "Mode" are not continuous variables, from the data you've given they are nominal and binary. There is no example in the training data of a mode 8 example, so that would be hard to predict without more training data.

Comment: @image_doctor,
Thats just example, to show you how I collect my data.
As you mention, that "KEY" and "MODE" must not be used, I do agree with you (maybe).
I use 120 song for corpus, 100 for training set and 20 for testing set.
WEKA? ehm, good advice. I like to try it soon, may be now. 
Hahh, wish you still say tune :D
thanks!

Comment: I was not suggesting that "KEY" and "MODE" should not be used, just that they are not real valued. Many algorithms, such as Random Forest, will be able to make good use of them as features. 120 songs doesn't sound like a large corpus, several thousand might be more appropriate if you have access to them, or perhaps this is just an exercise?  Do you use something like 10-fold cross validation to estimate your classification accuracy ? Good luck.